# Default lightbox for images gets disabled on using lazy load

Tags: javascript, css, image, lazy-loading

Well I was trying to make images load faster on blog using lazy load that's when the default lightbox for images got disabled.

Apparently there's something obstructing the lightbox functioning in the lazy load script.

Here is lazy load script I used

```
    (function () {
    function r(e) {
        var t = 0;
        if (e.offsetParent) {
            do t += e.offsetTop; while (e = e.offsetParent);
            return t
        }
    }
    var e = window.addEventListener || function (e, t) {
            window.attachEvent("on" + e, t)
        },
        t = window.removeEventListener || function (e, t, n) {
            window.detachEvent("on" + e, t)
        },
        n = {
            cache: [],
            mobileScreenSize: 500,
            addObservers: function () {
                e("scroll", n.throttledLoad), e("resize", n.throttledLoad)
            },
            removeObservers: function () {
                t("scroll", n.throttledLoad, !1), t("resize", n.throttledLoad, !1)
            },
            throttleTimer: (new Date).getTime(),
            throttledLoad: function () {
                var e = (new Date).getTime();
                e - n.throttleTimer >= 200 && (n.throttleTimer = e, n.loadVisibleImages())
            },
            loadVisibleImages: function () {
                var e = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
                    t = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight,
                    i = {
                        min: e - 300,
                        max: e + t + 300
                    },
                    s = 0;
                while (s < n.cache.length) {
                    var o = n.cache[s],
                        u = r(o),
                        a = o.height || 0;
                    if (u >= i.min - a && u <= i.max) {
                        var f = o.getAttribute("data-src-mobile");
                        o.onload = function () {
                            this.className = "lazy-loaded"
                        }, f && screen.width <= n.mobileScreenSize ? o.src = f : o.src = o.getAttribute("data-src"), o.removeAttribute("data-src"), o.removeAttribute("data-src-mobile"), n.cache.splice(s, 1);
                        continue
                    }
                    s++
                }
                n.cache.length === 0 && n.removeObservers()
            },
            init: function () {
                document.querySelectorAll || (document.querySelectorAll = function (e) {
                    var t = document,
                        n = t.documentElement.firstChild,
                        r = t.createElement("STYLE");
                    return n.appendChild(r), t.__qsaels = [], r.styleSheet.cssText = e + "{x:expression(document.__qsaels.push(this))}", window.scrollBy(0, 0), t.__qsaels
                }), e("load", function r() {
                    var e = document.querySelectorAll("img[data-src]");
                    for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
                        var s = e[i];
                        n.cache.push(s)
                    }
                    n.addObservers(), n.loadVisibleImages(), t("load", r, !1)
                })
            }
        };
    n.init()
})()
```

You can see the disabled effect here on this [site](http://geniushowto.blogspot.com) and the site with [no lazy load](http://geniusknight.blogspot.com/). Just click on any image from the post to check the lightbox functioning.

I guess the `lightbox` functioning comes in from an external source which somehow I wasn't able to trace. I guess the `data-src` and `src` of the original and ones loaded over cause something bad to the lightbox.

Is there something I am doing wrong here? A solution to the problem will be very helpful.

Edit: Here is the lightbox plugin that I found:

```
kj = "lightbox",

function Co(a) {
        var b = yo.V(),
            c = b.h,
            d = b.b;
        if (d.lightbox) a(d.lightbox[1]);
        else if (c.lightbox) c.lightbox[D]([1, a]);
        else c.lightbox = [
            [1, a]
        ], Q(b.a) ? Bo(b, kj) : b.d[D](kj)
    }

            if (this.a[x].lightboxEnabled) {
                var b = this.a[x].lightboxModuleUrl,
                    c = this.a[x].lightboxCssUrl,
                    d = pq.V(),
                    e = Rm(b);
                Ao(yo.V(), b, e);
                d.f = c;
                b = sn(Me, Yj, this.a.a);
                for (c = 0; c < b[H]; c++) {
                    for (var e = ni + ir++, d = pq.V(), f = sn(ff, void 0, b[c]), h = f[H], s = [], t = 0; t < h; t++) {
                        var z = f[t].src,
                            A = null,
                            I = Hn(f[t]);
                        if (I) {
                            I = I[sb];
                            if (I != z) {
                                var Wa = z,
                                    A = sq(I),
                                    Wa = sq(Wa);
                                if (A && Wa && A[A[H] - 1] ==
                                    Wa[Wa[H] - 1]) A = z, z = I, z = (I = sq(z)) && zm(I, td) ? z[w](/\/s(\d+)-h\//, Md) : z;
                                else continue
                            }
                            s[D]({
                                imageUrl: z,
                                thumbnailUrl: A
                            });
                            eo(f[t], ih, R(d.g, d, e, s[H] - 1))
                        }
                    }
                    0 < s[H] && (d.a[e] = s, d.d || (d.d = eo(k, lj, d.h, !1, d)))
                }
            }
```

here is the complete [minified version](https://www.blogger.com/static/v1/widgets/1599769820-widgets.js)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the exact lightbox you are using but I had a similar situation with a site I built where I was loading the images in after the page itself had finished loading and it broke the lightbox. The simplest solution (if your lightbox lets you do it easily) would be to call your lightbox function again after the images have been loaded.

Comment: Thanks @joseph I got the idea ! :)

Comment: hmm I found the js file including the lightbox plugin here have a look https://www.blogger.com/static/v1/widgets/1599769820-widgets.js search for "lightbox"

Comment: it's a completely different lightbox than the one you are using, but I use this method for my sites, and it's is very easy to use.http://fearlessflyer.com/how-to-add-lightbox-to-wp-without-plugin/

Not sure how helpful it will be to you.

Comment: Ooops blogger doesn't support php !!

Comment: PrettyPhoto runs on jQuery, the php code in that example is only used to install it. I haven't used blogger, but PrettyPhoto only "requires" jQuery as extra code. Again, it is totally different than your current lightbox, I was just sharing it in case it helped you or anyone else who finds this question in the future.

Comment: Thanks @Joseph for the lightbox plugin but It seems lazy load has other issues as well like social sharing images vanish so I am going to look for another lazy load and then enable the lightbox feature. :)

Comment: Gracias ! You too ! :D I will probably tweak the above lazy load script to eliminate usage of html in the images to avoid any issues altogether.:)